# C# SQLite INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

Tags: c#

I'm using SQLite in my application to store some `Message` objects. I display a list of `Message` items in "View 1". When I change a property in the Edit View "View 2", I want the property to also change in the list.

**Classes**

*Message.cs*

```
class Message : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private uint _id;
    public uint Id 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            // Trigger INotifyPropertyChanged
            Set("Id", ref _id, value);
        }
    }

    private string _content;
    public string Content 
    {
        get
        {
            return _content;
        }
        set
        {
            // Trigger INotifyPropertyChanged
            Set("Content", ref _content, value);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

*MessageViewModel.cs*

```
class MessageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Message message;

    ...

    private string _content;
    public string Content 
    {
        get
        {
            return message.Content;
        }
        set
        {
            // Set value
            message.Content = value;

            // Trigger INotifyPropertyChanged
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

**View 1**

*View1.xaml*

The datacontext is `View1ViewModel`

*View1ViewModel.cs*

```
private List<MessageViewModel> _messages;
public List<MessageViewModel> Messages
{
    get
    {
        return _messages;
    }
    set
    {
        // Trigger INotifyPropertyChanged
        Set("Messages", ref _messages, value);
    }
}

...

private async void loadMessages()
{
    // Get the messages from SQLite database
    var messages = await newMessages();
    Messages = new MessageViewModelCollection(messages);
}
```

**View 2**

*View2ViewModel.cs*

```
private MessageViewModel _message;
public MessageViewModel Message
{
    get
    {
        return _message;
    }
    set
    {
        // Trigger INotifyPropertyChanged
        Set("Message", ref _message, value);
    }
}

...

private async void loadMessage()
{
    // Get the message from SQLite database by Id
    var message = await newMessage(messageId);
    Message = new MessageViewModel(message);
}
```

The functions `newMessages` and `newMessage(uint messageId)` return `new` `Message` objects from the database.

I normally use the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation, but this doesn't work. I query the database 2 times, once for the list (View 1), and once for the edit page (View 2). The SQLite returns two different copies of the `Message` object, therefore the `INotifyPropertyChanged` meganism will not work (Only in the current page, not the pages in the backstack).

I could fix the problem by re-using the `Message` item from the list, but I cannot always do this in all views.

Is there a way to make the `INotifyPropertyChanged` work in this scenario? Or do I need a different approach to update the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a different approach. IMHO, the best thing would be to separate the data model from the view model. So have a `MessageVm` that binds to the WPF view, and put the logic into it to update itself appropriately (along with firing any necessary `INotifyPropertyChanged`'s) from the `Message` objects that get passed into it.

There are some automatic mapping tools like `Automapper` which might, to some degree, alleviate the pain that comes along with this approach.

But you really should separate the view model from the data model, the decoupling of these layers is one of the principle tenets of WPF programming.

Comment: I'm already using a `MessageViewModel` to bind to the WPF view. The problem still exists with a VM. The `Message` object changes, but the ViewModel for "View 1" and "View 2" are "watching" two different `Message` objects. Normally the two viewmodels will "watch" the same `Message` object.

Comment: Are you binding the `Message` objects to the list directly, though? Another words, does the `MessageViewModel` have two lists of `Message` objects which are binding to the WPF views? If so, you need to decouple that, otherwise you'll be looking at the challenge of undesired `INotifyPropertyChanged`'s getting called.

Comment: For "view 1", I use a `List<MessageViewModel>`. The view will bind to `MessageViewModel.PropertyA`. "View 2" only has one `MessageViewModel`, this `MessageViewModel` updates the `Message` object, which only fires `INotifyPropertyChanged` in "View 2".